# How to find the total derivative of a function $f_a(y(t),x(t))$ subjected to parametric change with the parameter $a$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals

It is well known to find the total derivative of a function $f(x(t),y(t))$. I consider it as $Td_f$. What, if the function depends upon some parameter, say, $a$. Then, how to find the total derivative of $f_a(x(t),y(t))$ such that the information of the parametric change will be included?

Can I just do $Td_{f_{a_1}}+Td_{f_{a_2}}$, or anything else in a more logical way?

Answer (score 1):

The total derivative of $f\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$ is :

$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$
Considering now the same function but depending on a parameter $a$, say $f_a\left(x(t),y(t)\right)$ :

If $a$ isn't function of $t$ and if $t$ is the only variable the total derivative is the same : 
$$\frac{df_a}{dt}=\frac{\partial f_a}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f_a}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}\qquad\qquad[1]$$

If $a$ is a function of $t$, say $a(t)$ , it can be considered as variable exactly as $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are :
$$f_a(x,y)\equiv f\left(x(t),y(t),a(t)\right)$$
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{da}{dt}\qquad\qquad[2]$$
Of course, if $a$ doesn't depends on $t$ we have $\frac{da}{dt}=0$ and Eq. $[2]$ is reduced to Eq. $[1]$.

If $a$ isn't function of $t$ and is considered as variable (it is written " subjected as parametric change with parameter $a$ " in the wording ) :
$$f_a(x,y)\equiv f\left(x(t),y(t),a\right)$$

One must distinguish "derivative with respect to $t$ " and "derivative with respect to $a$". It is less confusing to talk of differential instead of derivative because "derivative" implies to specify with respect to which variable. The total differential of the function $f$ is :

$$df=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)dt+\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}da \qquad \begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\quad \text{obviously}
\end{cases}$$